# How to integrate my application with Google Now cards

Tags: android

I want to integrate my application with Google Now Cards. Anything posted from my application should be shown as a card in Google Now.

Google is not provided any API for that. But there are 70 apps which are integrated with Google Now Cards. I want to know how they have done that and how can i integrate my application.

Comment: http://www.google.com/landing/now/integrations.html, they are saying like Now cards from apps are currently under development and are not available to all apps. We'll let you know when we are able to onboard more partners.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/schemas/now/cards lets go through this too

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. From [Google Now Integration Page](https://www.google.com/landing/now/integrations.html) :

> Now cards from apps are currently under development and are not available to all apps. We'll let you know when we are able to onboard more partners

**But** , it is possible to trigger cards from emails, maybe you can leverage that to your purpose. See [Docs](https://developers.google.com/schemas/tutorials/google-now-cards) from google

> ... use semantic markup in an email to trigger Google Now cards for the recipient. We will create a marked-up email, verify validity of the markup and check if the Google Now card triggered with the information included. ...

Comment: this is what i said in my comment

Comment: But, howz the other applications like bookmyshow is integrated ?